# how to change names of all directories / files containing a specific string on linux

Tags: linux, shell, unix, pipe

I have a directory where I want to change all of the directory names and files under it to a different name.  For example my directory structure is

```
./mydir_ABC/
./mydir_ABC/myfile_ABC.txt
./mydir_ABC/otherdir_ABC/
```

and I want to make it for example

```
./mydir_DEF/
./mydir_DEF/myfile_DEF.txt
./mydir_DEF/otherdir_DEF/
```

I am using

```
find . -type 'f' -name '*ABC*'
find . -type 'd' -name '*ABC*'
```

to get a list of all the relevant directories and files that contain my string in their names. How do I pipe it to another command that will actually change the directory names and file names? (I want it to be able to overwrite if the file or directory already exists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look up the `rename(1)` command.  There are some different variations on it, but they all support some sort of renaming based on regular expressions of some sort.  The version I use (based on code from the first edition of the Perl 'Camel Book') would be used as:

```
rename 's%ABC%DEF%g' ...
```

Or, for your example:

```
find . -print0 | xargs -0 rename s/ABC/DEF/g
```

Or, to avoid problems with path names changing while you're traversing the directory structure, do the directory names first, then the files (as in the question):

```
find . -type d -print0 | xargs -0 rename s/ABC/DEF/g
find . -type f -print0 | xargs -0 rename s/ABC/DEF/g
```

There could still be problems with renaming directories as you go (because once you've renamed `./ABC` to `./DEF`, you can no longer rename `./ABC/subABC/` to `./DEF/subDEF` because the directory is now `./DEF/subABC`).

Other versions of `rename` have different syntaxes - check your manual pages.

---

Here is the Perl-based version of `rename` derived from the first edition of the Perl 'Camel Book'; the first version I have under version control has a date of 1992-01-05.  Today's change updated the shebang line (uses env, removed `-w` since it is not reliable, and added `use warnings;` to compensate for no `-w`).  Prior changes were 2008, 1998, 1996 and 1992; it hasn't changed much over the last 19 years.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
#
# @(#)$Id: rename.pl,v 1.8 2011/06/03 22:30:22 jleffler Exp $
#
# Rename files using a Perl substitute or transliterate command

use strict;
use warnings;
use Getopt::Std;

my(%opts);
my($usage) = "Usage: $0 [-fnxV] perlexpr [filenames]\n";
my($force) = 0;
my($noexc) = 0;
my($trace) = 0;

die $usage unless getopts('fnxV', \%opts);

if ($opts{V})
{
    printf "%s\n", q'RENAME Version $Revision: 1.8 $ ($Date: 2011/06/03 22:30:22 $)';
    exit 0;
}
$force = 1 if ($opts{f});
$noexc = 1 if ($opts{n});
$trace = 1 if ($opts{x});

my($op) = shift;
die $usage unless defined $op;

if (!@ARGV) {
    @ARGV = <STDIN>;
    chop(@ARGV);
}

for (@ARGV)
{
    if (-e $_ || -l $_)
    {
        my($was) = $_;
        eval $op;
        die $@ if $@;
        next if ($was eq $_);
        if ($force == 0 && -f $_)
        {
            print STDERR "rename failed: $was - $_ exists\n";
        }
        else
        {
            print "+ $was --> $_\n" if $trace;
            print STDERR "rename failed: $was - $!\n"
                unless ($noexc || rename($was, $_));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        print STDERR "$_ - $!\n";
    }
}
```

Comment: this specifically didn't work, but i'll look into it more thanks. is it also able to rename directories ?

Comment: @Michael - I forgot to put the 'g' suffix on the 'find' version - sorry.  Yes, it can rename directories - but you might be better off renaming directories first and then files.

Comment: i'm not sure we are using the same rename command. my man page for rename is like the one on http://linux.die.net/man/1/rename  .the syntax looks different and i'm guessing that it's less powerful. i think your `rename(1)` doesn't come with my distro (RHEL5). i looked at ubuntu's man page for `rename(1)` and its different. more like what you suggested.

Comment: @michael - I identified where my version came from; you may well be right that the 'standard' version is less powerful.  I'll add the code to this answer.  (I changed it to fix the shebang line; my older coding standard forcibly changed the pathname to Perl when the file was 'compiled'.)

Answer (score 2):

```
mkdir z; cd z; touch fooabcbar; touch fooABCbar
find . -type 'f' \( -name '*ABC*' -o -name '*abc*' \) | while read f; do g=`echo "$f" | sed -e 's/abc/def/g' -e 's/ABC/DEF/g'`; echo mv -- "$f" "$g"; done
```

As long as the pathname doesn't include a newline (very rare).

Comment: bash has text replacement, so don't need sed: `g=${f//ABC/DEF}`

Comment: @Seth it gives me `while: Expression Syntax.`

Comment: @michael: You must have a copy-paste error.  I just tested this and it worked.  I will update the answer with the test case.

Comment: @seth sorry i can't make it work, i've checked and there is no copy-paste problem. what distro / shell are you using ?

Comment: @michael: I am using bash 4.2.10(2) on a linux system, but this is pure POSIX shell stuff that I have done since SunOS 3.  Perhaps you should pastebin the session where you type this example into your shell so we can see what is going on.  Another test of the while thing you should also include is `echo foo | while read f; do echo zoo$f; done`

Comment: @Seth i was using tcshell. after switching to bash it is working. thanks

Answer (score 0):

If it's always the last 3 characters this should work well enough I would think:

```
mv *abc.* *def.*
```

Comment: it's not limited to the last 3 chars, can be anywhere in the file/directory name.